Working remotely from Spain for a US role
I want to get the community help on the following.
My objective is to work for a US company with US salary, but do that remotely from Spain.
I am a lead data scientist with 10 years of experience as DS. I currently work in a big consultancy in the US. I want to go to Spain (that's where I am originally from). My US visa only allows me to work in my current company but not elsewhere.
My current plan is to apply for US jobs that are marked as remote, and  if they like me, later on in the process I can tell them to work from Spain. But not sure if it's a good idea.
Any thoughts?

You should be aware that US salaries are usually tied to the cost of living, i.e. much higher salaries in expensive cities and less so in moderate cities. Living abroad might not give you as much money as you're hoping for.

Even if you work in Spain, if you are working for an American company, and not an company in Spain owned by an American copy you will need authorization to work in America. Your visa is another issue. This second company might be unwilling to sponsor your visa. Your salary desires are not realistic

Can you clarify a few details :  (1) Are you currently located in Spain ? (2) Are you working for a US company now ? (3) Or, are you working for an off-shored company that is located outside the US, and that company is working with a US company ?

If it's just temporary, you should check if the US offers secondments (Posting of workers) to Spain. In Germany for example it's possible for up to two years to work in another country for your employer in Germany. In a secondment you work under the jurisdiction of the employers country. Also the social security and taxes are paid in your employers country. So it's easy. As I said, I don't know about the US law regarding this, but you can check out the EU website about it: https://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=471&langId=en

Define "later on in the process".  Presumably, the fact that your visa only allows you to work for your current employer will come up during a relatively early screening round of interviews at which point you'll need to explain your plan.
If you're applying for a company that doesn't have international employees, it is highly unlikely that they'd be willing to hire someone that plans on working remotely from Spain.  That would entail things like making sure that they're paying Spanish taxes correctly, making sure that they're complying with Spanish employment laws in terms of overtime, vacation time, holidays, etc.  That is a tremendous amount of work (and likely updates to HR systems) for just one person.
If you're applying for a company that already has employees working remotely from Spain, the company will probably be happy to talk to you.  But it is unlikely that they'd be willing to offer you a US-based salary.  They'd offer you a salary that is commensurate with the other employees based in Spain.

This will not work
To pay you while you reside overseas, a company would need to pay you through an intermediary who is familiar with local labor laws.  Even if this were not the case and you just hid that you lived in Spain, it wouldn't work because you couldn't get past the employment eligibility verification (I-9 process).
My company has done this for an existing worker who wanted to move to the UK.  They hired a UK firm to act as the local employer and meet all applicable labor and tax laws.  Literally no firm will do this for you as a new hire unless you are a superstar.  Like maybe if you were the lead designer for iPhones it could work, or you wrote the computer language the company is hiring for.
Ask yourself why firms such as HCL, TCS, Cognizant, etc., do so well consulting for companies by providing overseas staffing.  US Firms do not direct hire people in India.  Your attempt to do this in Spain is no different.

What you are asking for is unreasonable when you consider a few ancillary people.  As such you will have to prove yourself very valuable to a company in order to pull this off.  If it was easy many would be doing it.  Additionally, US companies are very good at discovering how to pay their workers less and as mentioned in the comments (infinitezero) you many end up with an average salary for Spain if you can pull this off.
The company will have to figure out how to navigate both Spanish and US laws concerning your employment.  They may have to run a special payroll just for you, which would be very expensive.  Then, if they allow you to do this, then they would have to allow the next person who wants to do the same thing in Sweden.
What happens if you are needed in the office?  They have may remote workers in Iowa, or whatever, but that if far less complex then coming from Spain.  Depending how remote you are in Spain and where the company is located, a 20 hour work day just for travel is not unreasonable.  Do you expect the company to pay for that time?
Its much easier to say "No", unless of course you are vital to their business.
Its also our election season right now and this kind of thing is not seen favorably by the voters, or politicians.
